# What is ReleaseDeployPhase.runPlanId and how it can be used?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

The `ReleaseDeployPhase` object schema is documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#releasedeployphase

It contains a GUID field `runPlanId`. What is this field and how can we use it in REST API?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what your objective is?

Comment: I am just curious as to what this field is. The documentation does not explain it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely used by the test plan integration capabilities. When a test plan is used to trigger a release, the `runPlanId` is populated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hmm, my releases are not triggered by a test plan, but they have non trivial `runPlanId`.